# VSTS PowerBI Integration - Cannot see nested Iteration Data

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, powerbi

I've retrieved data from an online VSTS instance in Power BI. However, I'm having an issue accessing "2nd level" iteration data.

For example, the VSTS iteration hierarchy is as follows. {Project}/Open/{Current Month}. I can see data up until the "Open" level, but I cannot drill down to the child iteration path.

Comment: Are you using Content Pack or Desktop Connector?

Answer (score 0):

We are deprecating the Power BI.com Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) Content Pack on November 15, 2017, you could try [the Analytics Marketplace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-analytics), or export the work item query to Excel and then import it to PowerBI.